# how pagination in the ext grid will work

Tags: extjs, pagination, grid

I am using this article of architecture http://blog.extjs.eu/know-how/writing-a-big-application-in-ext/

here is my Application.ResellerIroGrid.js
the pagination buttons are coming but no. of pages and pageno. is not coming .

```
Application.ResellerIroGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
     border:false
    ,cityname : ''
    ,columndataindex : ''
    ,fromdate:''
    ,todate : '' 
    ,initComponent:function() {
        var config = {
            store:new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                // store configs
                autoDestroy: true,
                autoLoad :false
                ,method: 'GET'
                ,baseParams: {
                    _command:'getresellersiro'
                    ,city:this.cityname
                    ,columndataindex : this.columndataindex
                    ,fromdate : this.fromdate
                    ,todate : this.todate
                }
                ,url: 'api/index.php'
                // reader configs
                ,root: 'reseller'
                ,totalProperty: 'totalcount'
                ,idProperty: 'mobile',
                fields: [
                   {name: 'caller'},
                   {name: 'designa'},
                   {name: 'mobile'},
                   {name: 'app_date'},
                   {name: 'transferto'},
                   {name: 'data_city'},
                   {name: 'AllocatedTo'},
                   {name: 'Parentid'},
                   {name: 'gotthru'}
                ]
            })
            ,columns: [
                {
                    id       :'caller',
                    header   : 'Caller', 
                    width    : 120, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'caller'
                },
                {
                    id       :'designa',
                    header   : ' Designation', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'designa'
                },
                 {
                    id       :'mobile',
                    header   : 'Mobile', 
                    height : 50,
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'mobile'
                },
                {
                    id       :'app_date',
                    header   : ' Appointment Date', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex : 'app_date'
                },
                {
                    id       :'transferto',
                    header   : ' Transfered To', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'transferto'
                },
                {
                    id       :'data_city',
                    header   : ' Data City', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'data_city'
                },
                {
                    id       :'AllocatedTo',
                    header   : ' Allocated To', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'AllocatedTo'
                },
                {
                    id       :'Parentid',
                    header   : ' Parent Id', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'Parentid'
                },
                {
                    id       :'gotthru',
                    header   : ' Appointment Type', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'gotthru'
                }
            ]
            ,plugins :[]
            ,viewConfig :{forceFit:true}
            ,tbar :[]
            ,bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                pageSize: 5,
                store: this.store,
                displayInfo: true,
                displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
                emptyMsg: "No topics to display"
            })
          ,height : 250
          ,width : 860
           ,title : 'Reseller Iro Grid'
        }; // eo config object

        // apply config
        Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
        Application.ResellerIroGrid.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    } // eo function initComponent
    ,onRender:function() {
        this.store.load();

        Application.ResellerIroGrid.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
    } // eo function onRender
});

Ext.reg('ResellerIroGrid', Application.ResellerIroGrid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a `totalProperty` attribute in your Store or JsonReader config and this property must be sent by ther server JSON.

Eg :

```
,totalProperty: 'totalCount'
,root: 'reseller',
,idProperty: 'caller'
```

Also, dont hardcode params in the store url property. You should use the `baseParams` config option for this :

```
method:'GET'
,baseParams: {
    _command:'getresellersiro'
    ,city:this.cityname
    [...]
}
,url:'api/index.php'
```

And of course you should have a PagingToolbar declared for your grid in the initComponent :

```
var pagesize = 5;

var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({ 
      [...]
      ,params:{start:0, limit:pagesize}
});

var paging_toolbar = new Ext.PagingToolbar({
    pageSize: pagesize,
    displayInfo: true,
    emptyMsg: 'No data',
    store: store
});

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store:store,
    [...]
    bbar:paging_toolbar
});
```

Comment: i changed to totalcount property and changed my json response like this {"reseller":[],"totalcount":10} but still my pagination is not coming , and changed the baseParams also but my request is going in POST why any ways first i want to solve the problem of pagination

Comment: totalcount with an uppercase C ? i mean the same as in the property

Comment: but in json response m using small and in my code of store m using small c , so is it ok ?

Comment: yes it should. but just edited my post with the most important part ;)

Comment: these thing already in the my file in the question please check what is incorrect in my file in bbar i have given the pagingtoolbar

Comment: yes. im not sure if 'this.store' will be available at that time the way you declare it. Try to first declare the store, then the pagingtoolbar, and then the grid in the initComponent.

Comment: how i will use this architecture for doing this ?

Comment: all in the initComponent : just extract the store and pagingtoolbar definition from config and create them before. then in config, references them wih store:store, bbar:paging_toolbar. You dont need to encapsulates anything in the 'config', you can create object before if you need to reference them in multiple objects (the store will be used in PagingToolbat and Grid)

Comment: okay cool now the count is coming proper but data is not coming proper means suppose i have 24 entries and page size is 5 so 5 pages coming right  , and the first page is displaying `1-23` but it should only display the `1-5` what should i do ?

Comment: your store should have these params : {start:0, limit:5} and your server use them to return the good rows

Comment: please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375377/how-data-in-grouping-grid-will-be-shown